# Selecting from tables that don't yet exist

Tags: mysql, sql

I am creating some reporting which summarises user  actions (clicks) from an online job board.

The MYSQL tables are structured so that there is one table for each days activities. The table names are standard (except for the date) e.g. 'User_Clicks_DD_MM_YYY'

I want to select from all of the tables (including future tables that have not yet been created) without having to revisit the code each day.

Does anyone know of a way that I can do this?

Comment: How can you select from table that doesn't exits ?

Comment: Use stored procedure with prepared statements.

Comment: Fix your data model!  You should not have a separate table for each day.  You should have *one* table with a date column specifying the day.  If necessary, you can use partitioning to improve performance, but that is another topic.

Comment: Basically having to ask this question should have flagged to you that the database design is wrong. Fix that and the query will be simple

Comment: It could be possible to write a stored procedure which builds a query based on which tables exist... However it would be better to change your schema so that you only have one table and a column for dates.

Comment: Unfortunately the database isn't owned by us, we are completing a project for another business and therefore we can't decide on how they store their data. There are tens of millions millions of clicks each day so I understand why they have stored the information in this way - however as you say, that's not helpful at this stage.

Comment: @golakwer Any more advice you might have around the stored procedure suggestion would be greatly appreciated. I assume you mean create a stored procedure which unions all of the existing tables?

Answer (score 0):

here is one way to approach this, it is a stored procedure that builds a query

what this does is, loops through a range of dates (you can substitute `now()` for the last date) and checks if a table exists for a particular date. if it does exist then it adds it to a select statement string. then the string is executed at the end of the proc.

```
create table tab_01_01_2020 (id int);
create table tab_02_01_2020 (id int);
insert into tab_01_01_2020 values (1);
insert into tab_02_01_2020 values (1);

DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test$$
CREATE PROCEDURE test()
BEGIN
    DECLARE count INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE mydate DATE;

    set mydate = '2020/01/01';

    set @qry='select 0 as id where 1 = 0';

    WHILE mydate < '2020/02/01' DO
        SET count = count + 1;

        set @day = (SELECT RIGHT(CONCAT('0',DAY(mydate)), 2));
        set @mon = (SELECT RIGHT(CONCAT('0',MONTH(mydate)), 2));
        set @tab = CONCAT('tab_',@day,'_',@mon,'_',YEAR(mydate));
        
        IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = DATABASE() AND table_name = @tab) = 1
        THEN
            set @qry = CONCAT(@qry, ' union select id from ', @tab);
        END IF;

        SET mydate = DATE_ADD(mydate, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
    END WHILE;

    select @qry;

    prepare stmt from @qry;
    execute stmt;
    deallocate prepare stmt;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

call test();
```